# Why athena table names should be unique globally?

Tags: amazon-athena

When I’m creating table in athena, it mentioned as tables names must be globally unique.
I created other database2 and had same tables as in database1. What’s the difference? I’m able to create tables with same_table_names.
It’s not restricting me as S3 does. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that table names must be globally unique? There is no such limitation. Table names must be unique within a database, but not globally. Depending on your definition of globally database names must not even be unique globally, just in an AWS region.

Comment: When we use create table wizard from athena console. It’s written there.

Comment: Can find out under table name tab

Comment: That is true, it does say "Table names must be globally unique." That's wrong. I've reported it to the Athena team, hopefully they will be able to change it.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my response, and upvote if you found it helpful.